# sharpziplib + extracting single file

Tags: c#, sharpziplib

Whenever i try to get the file, the length of the input stream (s.Length) is always zero, what am i doing wrong?  ZipEntry is valid and has the proper size of the file, etc.

Here is the code im using:

```
public static byte[] GetFileFromZip(string zipPath, string fileName)
{
    byte[] ret = null;
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipPath);
    ZipEntry ze = zf.GetEntry(fileName);

    if (ze != null)
    {
        Stream s = zf.GetInputStream(ze);
        ret = new byte[s.Length];
        s.Read(ret, 0, ret.Length);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The input stream will not have a length.  Use `ZipEntry.Size` instead.

```
public static byte[] GetFileFromZip(string zipPath, string fileName)
{
    byte[] ret = null;
    ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipPath);
    ZipEntry ze = zf.GetEntry(fileName);

    if (ze != null)
    {
        Stream s = zf.GetInputStream(ze);
        ret = new byte[ze.Size];
        s.Read(ret, 0, ret.Length);
    }

    return ret;
}
```